# Есть каталог с одеждой и фильтр к нему с параметрами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть каталог с одеждой и фильтр к нему с параметрами: категории, размер, цвет материал, цена. Понимаю как сверстать, сделать адаптивность....
Как сделать логику фильтра на стороне клиента (jquery).
Какие будут варианты?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен принцип работы? Если принцип работы, то он следующий - у вас после того как сверстаете будет блок с различными фильтрами, которые, само собой - инпуты. Ну вот и у вас есть 2 варианта работы.

1) Фильтровать при любом изменении любого фильтра из этого блока - тогда вешаете событие change \ keypress \ click на каждый элемент фильтра в зависимости от его принципа работы - Этот вариант сложнее, т.к. вам нужно вешать событие на все элементы, с другой стороны там варианты различаться будут только у радио\чекбокс снопок, полей ввода и, возможно, дат. Зато выглядит это более интерактивно и отзывчиво
2) Фильтровать только при нажатии на кнопку "Показать" - этот вариант проще в плане навешивания событий, т.к. событие вешаем только на одну кнопку.

А можно совместить эти варианты - есть пользователи которые не понимают что отфильтровалось уже после того как он передвинул ползунок и для точности предпочитают нажать кнопку.

После этого задача сводится к написанию функции, которая берет данные из всех этих фильтров, формирует массив фильтров, посылает AJAX запрос на бэк, который вернет только нужные элементы и затем уже заменяет имеющиеся элементы на те, что подходят фильтру и будут отправлены бэком.

Принцип работы довольно простой, так что просто проходитесь поочередно по пунктам и пытайтесь это сделать. А уже если где-то не понимаете почему\как - тогда задавайте снова вопрос. Но, естественно, полностью за вас никто это делать не будет :-)

Comment: понимаю.......))